# How to change the window title of UWP App

Tags: window, titlebar, xamarin.uwp

I create a new Xamarin project with Visual Studio and it contain projects for different platforms:

```
MyAppName
MyAppName.Droid
MyAppName.iOS
MyAppName.UWP
```

When I run the UWP App, the window title bar show the name "MyAppName.UWP".
I want to see only "MyAppName".

I have changed:
Assembly information / Title and Product

Package Manifest / Application / Display name and Description

Package Manifest / Packaging / Package display name

None of them have changed the title in the window title bar.

What I have to change?

Comment: You just need to modify `DisplayName` where in the Package Manifest file. And remove `.UWP` field. The title will be changed.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in a comment, to set the Window title for the UWP app you need to modify the `DisplayName` in the `Package.appmanifest` file.